# Put Image in contour (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I teach OpenCV, and I want to write a small test app. And have a question.
What algorithm would you advise to fill the contour (close to a rectangle) with image?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it would be better if you could add an image and then explain your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the location of the rectangle you would like to fill, you could simply set a ROI (region of interest) and perform some processing on that region (maybe a grayscale conversion), or even copy another image to that location. I've already demonstrated [how to set a ROI and perform some processing on that area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881397/setting-roi-with-mouse-from-a-rectangle-on-a-video/10883266#10883266).

If you want to add 2 images I suggest you check [the official tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html), [this post](http://www.developerstation.org/2011/02/adding-two-images-in-opencv.html), and [this demo](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut2.html): the magic happens through `cvSetImageROI()` and `cvAddWeighted()`.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of [warp](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-warpperspective) to deform the src image to match the shape of the contour and [addWeighted](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=addweighted) to replace destination image pixels with the source in the new shape