# convert one third of video stream to grayscale and display

Tags: opencv, webcam, grayscale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting ROI with mouse from a rectangle on a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881397/setting-roi-with-mouse-from-a-rectangle-on-a-video)

I am developing a simple application in opencv which will show a one third of video stream as grayscale, that one-third region is based on user's mouth detection. If the mouth is at extreme right then the right one-third of screen converts to grayscale. I am unable to find an approach to convert specific part to grayscale based on detection. Please can somebody identify the correct way of doing this.

I am using OpenCV version 2.3 in ubuntu

Comment: [Is this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881397/setting-roi-with-mouse-from-a-rectangle-on-a-video/10883266#10883266) what you are trying to do?

Comment: pretty much this, except the user selection part through mouse

Answer (score 1):

Use an roi to select the region of the source image you want to change, then cvtColor to make it grey

Comment: can you explain by code snippets?  I am pretty new to opencv

Comment: see the sample code in Karlphilli's link

Comment: i have a Mat image instead of IplImage , how to use cvtColor and set ROI for Mat image?